# Why is Linux switching off the ARM timer interrupt shortly after I enable it?

Tags: interrupts

When I set the [ARM timer control register's "timer enabled" bit](https://www.raspberrypi.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/BCM2835-ARM-Peripherals.pdf#page=197), it clears the interrupt ["enable basic IRQs" bit for the ARM timer](https://www.raspberrypi.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/BCM2835-ARM-Peripherals.pdf#page=117) after a brief delay. Why is this happening?

I ran this test:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

uint32_t* addr;

int main() {

    addr = (uint32_t*)mmap(
        NULL,
        4096,
        PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,
        MAP_SHARED,
        open("/dev/mem", O_RDWR | O_SYNC),
        0x2000B000
    );

    printf("\nenable basic IRQs = %u\n\n", *(addr + 128 + 6));

    printf("enable basic IRQs: set ARM Timer IRQ bit\n");
    *(addr + 128 + 6) = 1;

    printf("\nenable basic IRQs = %u\n\n", *(addr + 128 + 6));

    printf("100 ms delay\n");
    usleep(100000);

    printf("\nenable basic IRQs = %u\n\n", *(addr + 128 + 6));

    uint32_t load = 0x10000;
    printf("ARMtimer load: %u\n", load);
    *(addr + 256) = load;
    printf("100 ms delay\n");
    usleep(100000);

    printf("\nenable basic IRQs = %u\n\n", *(addr + 128 + 6));

    printf("ARMtimer control: timer enabled\n");
    *(addr + 256 + 2) |= (1 << 7);

    printf("\nenable basic IRQs = %u\n\n", *(addr + 128 + 6));

    printf("100 ms delay\n");
    usleep(100000);

    printf("\nenable basic IRQs = %u\n\n", *(addr + 128 + 6));
}
```

It produces this output:

```
enable basic IRQs = 6

enable basic IRQs: set ARM Timer IRQ bit

enable basic IRQs = 7

100 ms delay

enable basic IRQs = 7

ARMtimer load: 65536
100 ms delay

enable basic IRQs = 7

ARMtimer control: timer enabled

enable basic IRQs = 7

100 ms delay

enable basic IRQs = 6
```